# Elasticsearch : Sorting on inner hits

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a payload like this , same payload will be present in all the documents but weight for each tag will be different in each document.

```
{
  "tags": [
    {
      "tag": "tag1",
      "weight": 5
    },
    {
      "tag": "tag2",
      "weight": 10
    },
    {
      "tag": "tag3",
      "weight": 7
    }
  ]
}
```

I have used nested field in mapping since I want to match against an element of array instead of entire array.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "tags": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "tag": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "weight": {
              "type": "double"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My requirement is to search for the tag and sort that particular tag based on weight across the docuements.
I have tried below query , but it is not sorting as per expectation.

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50,
  "sort": [
    {
      "tags.weight": {
        "order": "asc",
        "nested_filter": {
          "term": {
            "tags.tag": "tag1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**EDIT** Added example

Exa:
Lets say there are 3 docs

```
{     
      "uid":1,
      "tags": [
        {
          "tag": "tag1",
          "weight": 5
        },
        {
          "tag": "tag2",
          "weight": 10
        },
        {
          "tag": "tag3",
          "weight": 7
        }
      ]
    },
{     
      "uid":2,
      "tags": [
        {
          "tag": "tag1",
          "weight": 9
        },
        {
          "tag": "tag2",
          "weight": 10
        },
        {
          "tag": "tag3",
          "weight": 7
        }
      ]
    },
{     
      "uid":3,
      "tags": [
        {
          "tag": "tag1",
          "weight": 7
        },
        {
          "tag": "tag2",
          "weight": 10
        },
        {
          "tag": "tag3",
          "weight": 7
        }
      ]
    }
```

When searched for "tag1"and sorted in ascending order, I should get below output
i.e Documents should get sorted according to weight for "tag1".

```
{
  "uid": 1,
  "tags": [
    {
      "tag": "tag1",
      "weight": 5
    },
    {
      "tag": "tag2",
      "weight": 10
    },
    {
      "tag": "tag3",
      "weight": 7
    }
  ]
},
{
  "uid": 3,
  "tags": [
    {
      "tag": "tag1",
      "weight": 7
    },
    {
      "tag": "tag2",
      "weight": 10
    },
    {
      "tag": "tag3",
      "weight": 7
    }
  ]
},
{
  "uid": 2,
  "tags": [
    {
      "tag": "tag1",
      "weight": 9
    },
    {
      "tag": "tag2",
      "weight": 10
    },
    {
      "tag": "tag3",
      "weight": 7
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Explain **_search for the tag and sort that particular tag based on weight across the docuements_** with example.

Comment: Thanks for reply Nishant ! I have edited my question with an example, please check

Comment: The path missing in your nested sort: "path": "tags", please retry.

Answer (score 5):

In the `inner_hits` propriety, you can set the `sort`.

Example:

```
"inner_hits":{
  "sort": [
    {
      "tags.tag": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, on the `result`, inside the `hits`, you will have the `inner_hits` propriety with the sorted objects.

Answer (score 1):

You were missing `path`/`nested_path` parameter. This is what you need:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50,
  "sort": [
    {
      "tags.weight": {
        "order": "asc",
        "nested": {
          "path": "tags",
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "tags.tag": "tag1"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

For older version of elastic:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50,
  "sort": [
    {
      "tags.weight": {
        "order": "asc",
        "nested_path": "tags",
        "nested_filter": {
          "term": {
            "tags.tag": "tag1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nishanat's answer is right.And in term query,you can use 'tags.tag.keyword' instead of 'tags.tag'